# Main App target and app's extension build number should be same?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-app-extension

In one app, I have 2 more extensions with their respective certificate as well as Provisioning profile. So at the time of uploading the build on App store, All three target should have the same build number or not. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Parth, did you able to solve your issu?

Answer (score 0):

All target version number should be same as main project's target.

Answer (score 0):

CFBundleVersion and CFBundleShortVersionString should be same for Extension target (*.appex) and its containing iOS app. Otherwise, warning will be thrown when you upload the build to appstore.

Warning will be like

> CFBundleVersion Mismatch - The CFBundleVersion value '1' of extension
>   'main.app/PlugIns/extension.appex' does not match the CFBundleVersion
>   value '1.0.3' of its containing iOS application 'main.app'.
>
> CFBundleShortVersionString Mismatch - The CFBundleShortVersionString
>   value '1.0' of extension 'main.app/PlugIns/extension.appex' does not
>   match the CFBundleShortVersionString value '1.0.3' of its containing
>   iOS application 'main.app'.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.